# Как написать css свойство только для Internet Explorer 10?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, internet-explorer

Internet Explorer 10 не поддерживает условные комментарии. Отсюда вопрос: как написать CSS св-во только для Internet Explorer 10?

Comment: Как вариант, я бы попробовал использовать JS, хоть вы и не упомянули в тэгах этот способ.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7321093/are-there-specific-css-selectors-targeting-ie10

Answer (score 1):

Отличная статья на данную тему:
https://www.kobzarev.com/makeup/ie10-css-hacks/

Мой любимый хак:

```
@media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active), (-ms-high-contrast: none) {  
   /* стили только для IE10 и 11 */ 
}
```